# Sci fi short story about a female activist that is really a clone of her virgin mother

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, clones

I read several years ago a short story about a female activist (told by her mother), that seemed like a “Jesus Christ in modern times story”... at the end you discover the mom is a biotechnician that cloned herself.

Comment: "Several years" could be 3, could be 40...Could you please be more specific about the time frame? Was this a in a magazine? Anthology? Online?

Comment: She did not clone herself. As she put it, "something made one of my eggs develop". Her old-time ex asks what could it have been, and she dares not answer, but remembers that day - 'the rustle of a million leaves'. "Not, it could not have been what she was sure it had been". But she named her daughter "J.C.".
(I also do not exactly remember where I read this).

Comment: @LSerni thanks, the "million leaves" triggered my memory! :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie the translation betrayed me. I read that in Italian and to be sure we'd get it, they had rendered the daughter's name as J.C., not Jaycie. So whatever search I tried returned nothing :-)

Answer (score 10):

[Mary and Joe by Naomi Mitchison](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93622). I read it in the anthology [Nova 1](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?194241). It was published in 1962.

Mary is a scientist and the activist daughter is *Jaycie*.

The fact that Jaycie is a clone is revealed when Jaycie is burned in an accident and Mary is able to provide skin grafts. The grafts are not rejected because Mary and Jaycie are genetically identical. When Mary's husband Joe asks about this Mary tells him:

> “But Mary,” he said, “a skin graft’s no good from someone else. Even I know that!”
>
> “It’s all right from someone identical: genetically the same.”
>
> “But Mary, you aren’t, you can’t be ... Joe had an uncomfortable feeling, though he didn’t quite know why.
>
> “Because of the father. His genes make the child different from the mother. I know. Joe, I told you a long time ago that Jaycie had a father. Joe, dear, dear Joe, I only told you that because I thought it would upset you more to think she hadn’t a father. There now, you are upset—”
>
> “Mary darling, don’t worry about me. I just don’t understand.”
>
> “She didn’t have a father, Joe. I - I never had a lover. I was - well, I suppose there is nothing else for it, I was a virgin, Joe.”
>
> “But you had a baby. Sweet, you can’t have been.”
>
> “I was. You see, something started one of my ova developing. That’s all. Oh that’s all! It doesn’t sound too odd that way, does it?”